# How to change the runlevel of a Linux service?

Tags: linux, services

this is what I have for a service runlevel after I list it:

```
runSomeService      0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

How do I make it so that "2:on" is "2:off"?  I've looked into the script that's supposed to start up and everything should be set to levels 3, 4 and 5.  I'm confused why I'm seeing this.

The OS is RHEL 6.8.

I've answered my own question.  I had an errant symlink inside of /etc/rc.d/rc2.d that was pointing to my service control script.

Comment: Please update your question and include the distribution (incl. version) you’re using. Linux is just the kernel.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. [su] is a question and answer site and answers should be separate from questions. You can [answer your own question](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) instead.